# If the arc length and chord length between two points in a circle are known , find radius of the circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

If the arc length and chord length between two points (two points on a circle that constitute a  minor arc ) in a circle are known , find radius of the circle?

Comment: What level of geometry do you know? Trigonometric functions?

Answer (score 3):

If the $O$ is the center of the circle, $A$ and
 $B$ are the end points of the chord and arc, then et $\alpha$ be an angle $\angle AOB$.

Let also $c$ - the length of the arc and $b$ - the length of $AB$, $d$ - diameter. Then we know that $$\alpha d/2 = c,$$
$$d\sin (\alpha/2)=b,$$
or $$ \sin \left(\frac{c}{d}\right)=\frac bd.$$
If $x = \frac cd$, then you are to solve an equation
$$\sin x = \frac bc x.$$

Comment: how to solve from b/c = sin x / x ? where the angle is unknown ?

Comment: @eagleseye: Numerical methods are appropriate.  See [more about the  (unnormalized) *sinc* or cardinal sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).  The Question I linked above led to [this earlier discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71839/how-can-i-find-an-upper-bound-for-the-radius-of-an-arc-given-arc-length-and-cho?lq=1) of numerical methods of solution.