# Formula to find radius of circle, given length of arc, and width of arc?

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

Let's say I have the Arc Length, and Width of that Arc... Is there a formula to find the radius of that circle?

Please See picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxH8Z.jpg

Arc Length is ACB, Arc Width is AB

Comment: What do you mean by width of arc?

Comment: What is "Width of arc"?

Comment: The answer is most likely "yes, there is a formula," but it might not be pretty.

Comment: I assume "width" is the distance between the end points? Then what you are given is $r\alpha$ and $2r\sin\frac\alpha2$ with $\alpha, r$ unknown ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [arc length and cord length](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714138/if-the-arc-length-and-chord-length-between-two-points-in-a-circle-are-known-fi?rq=1) and [arc length and endpoints](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21072/finding-out-an-arcs-radius-by-arc-length-and-endpoints)

Comment: I added a picture to the description; This should clear up any confusions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding out an arc's radius by arc length and endpoints](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21072/finding-out-an-arcs-radius-by-arc-length-and-endpoints)

Answer (score 3):

There is no closed-form formula.

Let $\theta$ be the half aperture angle. Then the half arc length is

$$a:=r\theta$$

and the half arc "width"

$$w:=r\sin\theta.$$

Taking the ratio, you get a transcendental equation

$$\frac{\sin\theta}\theta=\text{sinc }\theta=\frac wa$$ and $$\theta=\text{sinc}^{-1}\dfrac wa$$ (the inverse *cardinal sine* function), but this is not considered a usual function.

For the same reason, there is no closed-form formula for $r$, because that would create one for $\theta$.

For small angles, you can use the Taylor development to the fourth or even sixth degree, and solve the biquadratic or triquadratic

$$\frac wa=\color{#0247fe}{\text{sinc }\theta}\approx\color{#32cd32}{1-\frac{\theta^2}6+\frac{\theta^4}{120}}\approx\color{magenta}{1-\frac{\theta^2}6+\frac{\theta^4}{120}-\frac{\theta^6}{5040}}$$ then refine with Newton.

[image]

Comment: @ccorn: thanks, I fixed.