# Radius of the circle.

Tags: circles

I am given that for two points $A, B$ on a circle, the length of the arc from $A$ to $B$ is $15$ whereas the length of the chord $\overline{AB}$ is $14$. How can I find the radius of the concerned circle?

Comment: What curve? Do you mean that you are given that for two point $A,B$ on a circle, the length of the *arc* from $A$ to $B$ is 15 whereas the length of the chord $\overline{AB}$ is 14? Having at least one complete sentence would greatly help understand the problem statement ...

Comment: This is a very poorly worded question. Try to enhance it lest it will be downvoted/closed.

Comment: I am Asking about circular curve.Arc length is 15 and the chord length is 14.so how to find Radius of the Curve ??

Comment: See [this well-asked and well-answered earlier question. ](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21072/finding-out-an-arcs-radius-by-arc-length-and-endpoints)

Answer (score 2):

If $r$ is the radius and $2\alpha$ the subtended angle, the the arc length is given by $15=2r\alpha$ and the chord length by $14=2r\sin\alpha$. Thus by eliminating $r$, we find the condition 
$$\tag1\frac{\sin \alpha}\alpha=\frac{14}{15} $$
for $\alpha$. Numerically$^{[1]}$, we obtain $\alpha\approx 0.63894677233$ and hence $r=\frac{15}{2\alpha}\approx 11.738$ and finally for the height of the segment $h=r(1-\cos\alpha)\approx 2.3156$.

$^{[1]}$ Unfortunately, there is no elementary way to solve $(1)$

Answer (score 1):

$\theta=$angle subtended by half arc at the center $=\frac{15/2}{r}=\frac{15}{2r}\tag 1$

now, consider a right triangle $$\sin \theta=\frac{14/2}{r}=\frac 7r\tag 2$$
dividing (2) by (1), $$\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=\frac{7/r}{15/2r}=\frac{14}{15}$$
solving above equation gives, $\theta\approx 0.638947$

now, you can take from here