# Roots of an arc-length system

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, roots, arc-length

Related:

- [Calculating the height of a circular segment at all points provided only chord and arc lengths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8487/calculating-the-height-of-a-circular-segment-at-all-points-provided-only-chord-a) - but this doesn't care about height, and doesn't have the arc-angle as a given
- [Finding out an arc's radius by arc length and endpoints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21072/finding-out-an-arcs-radius-by-arc-length-and-endpoints) - pretty close, but I do not have the same 180° constraint, and I need offset angles for both endpoints in the chord, not just the angle between them

The not-particularly-relevant background is that I'm writing visualisation to project a network from non-Euclidean space to Euclidean space, and inter-node distances are usually higher than what straight lines permit so I need to draw curves (really, of any kind). Arcs seem like the simplest option.

This is an excerpt from a working but slow solution:

[image: noneuclidean]

Given

- coordinates of ingress node $a$, represented as an arc endpoint;
- coordinates of egress node $b$, represented as an arc endpoint;
- arc-length $l$;

I need (for *matplotlib* ellipsoidal arc patches) the circle centre $c$, radius $r$, and angles $\theta_a$, $\theta_b$ to each end of the arc. Convexity-like orientation of the arc doesn't matter. I've already calculated chord length but in my current solution this is not applicable.

I have a working, mostly-brute-force solution where I run the following system of equations through [least-squares root-finding](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) to determine $c$, $\theta$ and radius $r$:

$$r^2 = (a_x - c_x)^2 + (a_y - c_y)^2$$
$$r^2 = (b_x - c_x)^2 + (b_y - c_y)^2$$
$$a_x = c_x + r \cos(\theta_a)$$
$$a_y = c_y + r \sin(\theta_a)$$
$$b_x = c_x + r \cos(\theta_b)$$
$$b_y = c_y + r \sin(\theta_b) $$
$$ \theta_b = \theta_a + l/r $$

It works(ish), and depending on the network edge converges in ~20-200 iterations. That's not great.

Things that could help:

- an analytic solution (though I doubt this is possible)?
- better initial estimate than $c=(a+b)/2, \theta_a=0, r=100$?
- leverage [@Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici)'s quite-interesting [polynomial expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3868219/54983), if that's applicable?

I also think that the first two ($r^2=...$) equations might be redundant, but without them, the output is often incorrect.

Comment: Fix the typo's in the first and second equation (I suppose - instead of =). Are the unknown only $(c_x,c_y,\theta_a,\theta_b,r)$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes, those are the unknowns.

Comment: Forget the first and second equations. Eliminate $(c_x,c_y,\theta_b)$ to face two equations in $(r,\theta_a)$